# Powershell - Invoke-RestMethod to get all links

Tags: html, powershell, rest

Trying to connect to webpage and return a list of all the file names listed there.

I wont include the whole code (to generate token etc), but using the below I can return the whole HTML doc.

```
$r = invoke-RestMethod $url -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $bearerToken"}
```

But I want to just get out the names of all the zip files, so in the below example I just want to return : `1_1_!!_DEV_ORG_HIER.zip`

```
    <td>
      <a href="/xxxxxxx/rest/DEFAULT/20/file/deployments/1_1_%21%21_DEV_ORG_HIER.zip">1_1_!!_DEV_ORG_HIER.zip</a>
   </td>
```

Tried various things and plenty of googling, but no joy, I'm sure its something simple that is eluding me.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to achieve what I wanted by using

`Invoke-WebRequest` rather than `Invoke-RestMethod`

As below.

```
$r = (Invoke-WebRequest $url -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $bearerToken"}).links.innerhtml
```